# Arbitrary character printed while manipulating string

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, c-strings

I made the user defined function STR_LEN_BUFFER to mimic the behaviour of the strcpy, but instead of copying the null character '\0', it would continue printing spaces to fill in the resultant string, whose length is specified by MAX_LEN (set to 15 in this case). Filling with arbitrary character (a smiley in this case?) only occurs while the input string has length less than 8.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 15
int i;
int max_len;
char Buffer_Space[MAX_LEN]="";
char* STR_LEN_BUFFER(char* og);
void main()
{ 
    int n;
    char ipstring[MAX_LEN];
    printf("Enter your string\n");
    scanf("%s",ipstring);   
    printf("\n");
    printf("your string modified\n");
    printf("%s",STR_LEN_BUFFER(ipstring));
    printf("<- this would be the starting position of the next string");
}

char* STR_LEN_BUFFER(char* og){
    
    for(i=0;i<MAX_LEN;i++){
        if(og[i]!='\0')
        Buffer_Space[i]+=og[i];
        else
        Buffer_Space[i]+=' ';
    }
    return Buffer_Space;
}
```

Output:
Enter your string
Hey

your string modified
Hey     ☺      <- this would be the starting position of the next string

Comment: What is your question? Why are you using `+=`?

Answer (score 0):

For starters as the passed string is not changed within the function `STR_LEN_BUFFER` then its parameter should have qualifier `const`.

```
char* STR_LEN_BUFFER(const char* og);
```

If you are using the format string `%s` in this call of `printf`

```
printf("%s",STR_LEN_BUFFER(ipstring));
```

then the expression `STR_LEN_BUFFER(ipstring)` must yield a string. Otherwise you should use the format string `"%.*s"` like

```
printf("%.*s", MAX_LEN, STR_LEN_BUFFER(ipstring));
```

As you are using the compound assignment operator `+=` instead of the assignment operator `=`

```
Buffer_Space[i]+=og[i];
```

and

```
Buffer_Space[i]+=' ';
```

then you can get an unexpected result in second and subsequent calls of the function. You should use the assignment operator = instead of the compound assignment operator `+=.`

The global variable `max_len` declared like

```
int max_len;
```

is not used in your program. Also there is no sense to declare the variable `i` used in the function as global.

As the variable `ipstring` with automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly

```
char ipstring[MAX_LEN];
```

it contains elements with indeterminate values. So using this if statement within the function `STR_LEN_BUFFER`

```
if(og[i]!='\0')
```

results in undefined behavior. The function can be defined the following way

```
char * STR_LEN_BUFFER( const char *og )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i + 1 < MAX_LEN &&  og[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        Buffer_Space[i] = og[i];
    }

    for ( ; i + 1 < MAX_LEN; i++ )
    {
        Buffer_Space[i] = ' ';
    }

    return Buffer_Space;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 15

char Buffer_Space[MAX_LEN]="";

char * STR_LEN_BUFFER( const char *og )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i + 1 < MAX_LEN &&  og[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        Buffer_Space[i] = og[i];
    }

    for ( ; i + 1 < MAX_LEN; i++ )
    {
        Buffer_Space[i] = ' ';
    }

    return Buffer_Space;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char ipstring[MAX_LEN];
    
    printf("Enter your string\n");
    scanf("%s",ipstring);
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("your string modified\n");
    printf("\"%s\"\n",STR_LEN_BUFFER(ipstring));
}
```

If to enter string

```
Hello
```

then the program output will be

```
your string modified
"Hello         "
```

Comment: I've never used `size_t` before(have seen it being used, but never used) personally. 1) Would it have any advantages over using `int` instead ?  2) and the reason `while ( i + 1 < MAX_LEN &&  og[i] != '\0' )` is better than `if(og[i]!='\0')` is because we're checking both the index and the string ? How does that work ?

Comment: I've made the changes as you said (both the user defined function and in main), but the program still doesn't work. nothing is printed onto the console after "your string modified"

Comment: @Aloy I am sorry there was a mistake. See my updated post.

Comment: it works now. Thanks. can you help me with the questions I posted in the first question ?

Comment: @Aloy size_t is an unsigned integer type usually correspondent to the type unsigned long  that is the type returned by the operator sizeof.

Comment: and why is adding the additional condition of `i+1< MAX_LEN` effective, compared to just `og[i] != '\0'` ?

Comment: @Aloy In general the user can pass a string of any length.